# Does batch size matter in inferencing speed?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp

I am reading the paper ["Are Sixteen Heads Really Better than One?"](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1905.10650.pdf) and in section 4.3 it states that the inference speed varies with batch size.

[image]

How does batch size affect inference speed for this machine learning model?

Comment: Might be worth emailing the original authors of the paper :)

Comment: With Batches, you can get the benefit of Vectorization.